# Multiple Starter Triggers in an Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I am looking at creating a logic app that needs to be triggered by multiple SharePoint Online Document Libraries. The examples I have seen don't actually show a second trigger, does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can an Azure Logic App have multiple start triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319340/can-an-azure-logic-app-have-multiple-start-triggers)

Comment: It is, but there are no examples of how this is done as a starting trigger

Comment: See the duplicate question: `Probably, what you mean instead is if it's possible to have multiple "starting" triggers to implement some kind of "or logic" between triggers. In this case I think the answer is no` Those seems to be not supported. Sorry, I originally was thinking the opposite

Comment: I must have missed that, thanks for the response @IgorSoloydenko

Comment: Technically it is possible, but the visual designer does not support multiple triggers, so I would advise against it. One approach you can follow is to have a child logic app (with a request trigger) and then multiple parent logic apps (one per each trigger) that just invoke the child logic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of multiple Triggers in a single Logic App, it would generally be better to separate the Trigger Logic Apps and processing Logic App.

Then, each Trigger Logic App, as many as you need, would call the single processing Logic App.

Comment: There are certain requirements where having different logic app is not a great idea. For e.g. if you have 4 folders and each folders with 2 sub folders on SFTP server and you have to use  SFTP "add or modified" trigger and create a blob. SFTP trigger doesnot accept multiple paths nor does it iterate through all sub folders in root folder. In this case one ends up with 8 logic apps absolutely doing the same thing each one pointing at different folder.

Answer (score 1):

We can create multiple starter triggers. Start with Recurrence action then add more than 1 triggers. See below image.

[image: Multiple starter triggers]

Comment: Does this actually exist?