# Service Bus Topic to ADLS using Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm new to Logic Apps and i have some basic questions. I created the below workflow (1 Trigger + 2 Actions) Where:

1) Reading for any new messages in Azure Service Bus Topic.

2) Then Load the data to Azure Data Lake respective Folders.

[image]

With regard to this i have some queries:

- In ADLS i'm creating folder like [Subject Area]\YYYY\MM\DD. So from a
  design perspective is there a way to skip the second step (ADLS
  Create Folder) or the workflow will ignore if the target folder
  exists.
- If i have 4 different Subject Areas then do i need to create 4
  instances of Logic Apps.
- With respect to Function App and Azure Logic Apps which is more
  economical. And how do i scale and Monitor my logic App execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert conditional steps in Logic Apps, so you could test if the target folder already exists.

What do you mean by "Subject Area"? If you want to write to different locations, then you can add a step for each one in the same Logic App.

Personally, I find Logic Apps easy to set up and get something going, like you did already. I find it harder to maintain later on. If the workflow gets more complicated and changes once in a while, I prefer to code everything up in a Function App and put it in version control. That gives me more control. I'd say if your flow becomes hard to manage in Logic Apps, consider using Function Apps. You can also mix: Function Apps can be a step within a Logic App.

Comment: Could you please help with the function/expression that i need to use in Conditional step that will check if a given folder exists or not.

Comment: And to your question on What do you mean by "Subject Area"?

There are few topics created for different subject/business area. And the application will push any new/updated data to those topics. So i have to create subscription for those topics and listen for any change using logic app trigger for Service bus topic

Comment: You would first add a step to check whether the target directory exists. The you would add a "Condition" based on the result of the previous check. About your second comment: Apparently [it's possible to have multiple triggers in one Logic app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43319340/2272514), so you would create one trigger per subscription.